# Poison msgs in WebLogic JMS

Tags: jms, weblogic

I know how to publish simple msg to a Queue or Topic in weblogic JMS and how to get subscribe those msgs.  I use standalone Pojo to send and receive the msgs.

Can you tell me if I can force the msg to become a Poison msg? If yes, what is the easiest way to force a msg to get poisoned?

The reason I wish to do so is to test if those poison msgs go to my error Q which I had configured.

I searched alot but fail to find such a demonstration of JMS msgs turning poisoned.

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/apirefs.1111/e13952/taskhelp/jms_modules/queues/ManageQueues.html

Poison messages are implementation-specific, so you'll have to work out what kind of garbage data you need to make your consumers reject it. Perhaps send an empty message, or one of the wrong type (object message vs text message)